# Cannot find route after adding api.listen to Express JS API

Tags: node.js, express

Some context:

- Node version: 10.16.0
- Express JS version: 4.17.1

I had the following code which is working fine:

```
import express from 'express';
const api = express();

api.use('/', () => {...});

.... add all the endpoints here

api.use((req, res, next) => {
  // this is my catch all endpoints endpoint
  throw error ('route not found');
}

api.use(customErrorHandlingMiddleware);

export default api;
```

Now, I want to add a function that runs on the start of API. For this, I read online that I should use api.listen() function.

This is my latest code:

```
import express from 'express';
const api = express();

api.use('/', () => {...});

.... add all the endpoints here

api.use((req, res, next) => {
  // this is my catch all endpoints endpoint
  throw error ('route not found');
}

api.use(customErrorHandlingMiddleware);

api.listen(5001, () => {
  customOnStartFunction();
})

export default api;
```

Before continuing, I want to mention one thing: I'm using Firebase Functions and running them locally for now (using Firebase Function Emulator), that is why I have the API listening on 5001. I'm not sure if I should change that.

Now, the customOnStartFunction is running whenever I make a save (I have tsc on watch mode), however, whenever I try to send a request to another endpoint, it's throwing the catch all endpoint error, meaning that it cannot find the route I'm requesting. The error goes away if I remove the `api.listen` code.

I've checked online and they put `api.listen` at the end of the code, but I tried putting this code in different places, only to get the same result. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help appreciated.

Comment: what is `customOnStartFunction` doing ??

Comment: Please impl error handling into the `listen` fn. `api.listen(5001, (err) => {
  if(err){
    console.error(err)
  }else{
  customOnStartFunction();
  }
})`

Comment: @ME-ON1 it gets all the routes in the API and stores it in a config file

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's done, I had to use `api.listen()` without specifying a port! Al l this time I was specifying port 5001 because that's what firebase uses